# Group Travel Salesman Problem

Tags: graph-theory, approximation-algorithms

For the following Group Traveling Salesman problem, I'd like to know if there exists some poly-time approximation algorithm with constant approximation factor.

Group TSP is defined as follows: Take a graph $G$ and a number of sets of nodes of $G$. The problem is to find the shortest path passing through at least one node in each node set. If each node set consists of only one node, the problem degenerates to classical TSP.

Comment: The paper Approximation algorithms for the geometric covering salesman problem, Esther M. Arkin and Refael Hassin, Discrete Applied Mathematics 55(3), 197-218 (1994), http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0166-218X(94)90008-6 contains approximation results for graphs with geometric structure.

Comment: What are your assumptions on the distances? WIthout any assumptions it is NP-hard to approximate TSP with any polynomial time computable function as approximation factor. For the Euclidean case you might want to look at http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/11523468_90

Comment: @ThomasKalinowski. Thanks Thomas for your reply which is indeed very useful. A related problem: if I am looking for the shortest path passing at least each node in $M$ node sets (in case where $M$ equals to the number of node sets, the problem degenerates to the group TSP), is there any approximation algorithm?